# USing React with Loopback

Tags: api, reactjs, loopbackjs

I did my API using Loopback and I'm wondering what should I use to render data in the frontend. So I thought about React.
What's the best solution for using React with Loopback While I'm really new to React, so can anybody tell me how to begin mixing these 2 technologies?

Answer (score -1):

[React-Loopback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loopback) is the best solution to integrate react with loopback. It is fairly tricky however, if your syntax doesn't use JSX, ES6 (Promises and Fetch)